# How to combine two solutions retaining SVN history for both?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a client that uses SVN for source control and TortoiseSVN on the desktop.

Generally (though not consistently) they use it like:

- Repository

  - \applications

    - \BusinessLine1

      - \Application1

        - \Branches
        - \Trunk
      - \Application2

        - \Branches
        - \Trunk
    - \BusinessLine2

      - \Application3

        - \Branches
        - \Trunk
      - etc...

I am contained to BusinessLine1 via permissions.

App1 and App2 are both .NET solutions. A Website, and WebServices. The Website is the only client for the WebServices and they share the same dev cycle.

Is it possible to combine the solutions/projects into one, without losing the history from each?

I've found the following but the difference is these are still separate codebases where as I'm essentially trying to intermingle files while still keeping the history for each.

- [Combining multiple SVN repositories into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267256/combining-multiple-svn-repositories-into-one)
- [How to merge two seperate - yet similar - codebases into one SVN rep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004600/how-to-merge-two-seperate-yet-similar-codebases-into-one-svn-rep)

To be clear, I know how to combine the projects into one solution in Visual Studio, I'm specifically looking for info about how to do this and retain the history for each file in SVN if at all possible.

Comment: The links you provided are for combining multiple SVN repositories. From the directory structure you've listed here, it looks like you want to simply do an `svn move` or `svn copy` from one directory to another because everything resides in one repository. In which yes, the history will still be retained because once something is committed to a repository, it will always remain in the version history.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't view it from that perspective. I'll give it a shot.